# How can I fix 'Error inflating class Spinner'

Tags: android, macos

Any clues or tips of how I could resolve this error in Android Studio (Bumblebee 2021.1.1 Patch 2). My OS is macOS Monterey 12.3.

**Error log file output**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.sdaproject2021, PID: 1777
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sdaproject2021/com.example.sdaproject2021.InteractiveMap}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #53: Binary XML file line #53: Error inflating class Spinner
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:150)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #53: Binary XML file line #53: Error inflating class Spinner
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:706)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
        at com.example.sdaproject2021.InteractiveMap.onCreate(InteractiveMap.java:62)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6294)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:150) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #53: Error inflating class Spinner
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:782)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:706) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195) 
        at com.example.sdaproject2021.InteractiveMap.onCreate(InteractiveMap.java:62) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6294) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:150) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at
```

**This is my XML**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
    
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonShowEvent"
            android:layout_width="224dp"
            android:layout_height="49dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:text="@string/show_what_i_can_do"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.508"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spinnerYear" />
    
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonShowNearestClub"
            android:layout_width="221dp"
            android:layout_height="54dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:text="@string/show_nearest_club"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/buttonShowEvent" />
    
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewLogo"
            android:layout_width="157dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_logo"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.535"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_cg_logo" />
    
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinnerMonth"
            android:layout_width="226dp"
            android:layout_height="52dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/birth_month"
            android:entries="@array/birth_month"
            android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageViewLogo"
            tools:ignore="DuplicateSpeakableTextCheck" />
    
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinnerYear"
            android:layout_width="225dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/birth_year"
            android:entries="@array/birth_year"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spinnerMonth"
            tools:ignore="DuplicateSpeakableTextCheck" />
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewMonth"
            android:layout_width="96dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="72dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
            android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/month_label"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/spinnerMonth"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
            android:text="@string/enter_date_of_birth"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageViewLogo" />
    
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="82dp"
            android:layout_height="46dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="72dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/year_label"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/spinnerYear"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewMonth" />
    
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I don't error when I run my app on the emulator only when I try to run it on my Android phone (Vodafone VFD 600, OS Version: Marshmallow 6.0.1)

**MainActivity**

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
        public static final String SHARED_PREF_USER_DOB = "UsersDOB";
        public static final String DOB_MONTH = "month";
        public static final String DOB_YEAR = "year";
    
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor; // used to save SharedPref
    
        static private final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    
        public Button mButtonShowEvents;
        public Button mButtonNearestClub;
        public Spinner mSpinnerMonth;
        public Spinner mSpinnerYear;
        public String mBirthMonth;
        public String mBirthYear;
        public int age;
    
    
    
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
            mButtonShowEvents = findViewById(R.id.buttonShowEvent);
            mButtonNearestClub = findViewById(R.id.buttonShowNearestClub);
    
            // Get a reference to the Spinners for birth month and year
            mSpinnerMonth = findViewById(R.id.spinnerMonth);
            mSpinnerYear = findViewById(R.id.spinnerYear);
    
            //Text Spinner - Android Studio Tutorial
            //https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=on_OrrX7Nw4
            // Create an Adapter that holds a list of months
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterMonth = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                    this, R.array.birth_month, R.layout.dropdown_list_month);
    
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterYear = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                    this, R.array.birth_year, R.layout.dropdown_list_year);
    
            // Set the Adapter for the spinner
            mSpinnerMonth.setAdapter(adapterMonth);
            mSpinnerYear.setAdapter(adapterYear);
    
            // Set an setOnItemSelectedListener on the spinnerMonth
            mSpinnerMonth.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                           int position, long id) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "onItemSelected: Birth month selected");
                    mBirthMonth = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), mBirthMonth + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
    
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                }
            });
            // Set an setOnItemSelectedListener on the spinnerYear
            mSpinnerYear.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                           int position, long id) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "onItemSelected: Birth year selected");
                    mBirthYear = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), mBirthYear + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
    
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                }
            });
    
            mButtonShowEvents.setOnClickListener((View v) -> {
                //check birth month and year have been selected before showing ConfirmationAndEvents Activity
                //https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/whatever/how+to+get+selected+item+from+spinner+in+android
    
                String stringMonth = mSpinnerMonth.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String stringYear = mSpinnerYear.getSelectedItem().toString();
    
                if(stringMonth.equals(" ")||stringYear.equals(" ")){
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Please select a month and year ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else {
                    //Toast.makeText(this, "D.O.B: " +stringMonth +" "+ stringYear, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    showAgeCategory(mBirthMonth, mBirthYear);
                }
    
                saveDateOfBirth();
            });
    
            //show map
            mButtonNearestClub.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                saveDateOfBirth();
                showNearestClub();
            });
        }
    
        private void saveDateOfBirth() {
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_USER_DOB, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    
            editor.putString(DOB_MONTH, mBirthMonth);
            editor.putString(DOB_YEAR, mBirthYear);
    
            editor.apply();
        }
    
    
        //Run query on db based on selected birth month and year and display age category and events in ConfirmationAndEvents activity
        private void showAgeCategory(String BirthMonth, String BirthYear){
            Log.i(TAG, "showAgeCategory: ");
    
            mBirthMonth = BirthMonth;
            mBirthYear = BirthYear;
    
            Toast.makeText(this, "Age category: " +mBirthYear+" "+ mBirthMonth, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    
            Intent intentShowAgeCategory = new Intent(this, ConfirmationAndEvents.class);
    
            // create text to display in textViewConfirmOfAge
    
            //get birth month and year
            List<String> jan_july = Arrays.asList("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July");
    
            // The key date for calculating is 31st July
            switch (mBirthYear) {
                case "2006":
                    if (jan_july.contains(mBirthMonth)) {
                        age = 16;
                        String mConfirmMessage = confirmationStatement();
                        intentShowAgeCategory.putExtra("Confirmation", mConfirmMessage);
                        intentShowAgeCategory.putExtra("User age", age);
                    } else {
                        age = 15;
                        String mConfirmMessage = confirmationStatement();
                        intentShowAgeCategory.putExtra("Confirmation", mConfirmMessage);
                    }
                    break;
                    case "2007":
                        if (jan_july.contains(BirthMonth)) {
                            age = 15;
                            String mConfirmMessage = confirmationStatement();
                            intentShowAgeCategory.putExtra("Confirmation", mConfirmMessage);
                        } else {
                            age = 14;
                            String mConfirmMessage = confirmationStatement();
                            intentShowAgeCategory.putExtra("Confirmation", mConfirmMessage);
                        }
                        break;
                    case "2008":
                        if (jan_july.contains(BirthMonth)) {
                            age = 14;
                            String mConfirmMessage = confirmationStatement();
                            intentShowAgeCategory.putExtra("Confirmation", mConfirmMessage);
                        } else {
                            age = 13;
                            String mConfirmMessage = confirmationStatement();
                            intentShowAgeCategory.putExtra("Confirmation", mConfirmMessage);
                        }
                        break;
                    case "2009":
                        if (jan_july.contains(BirthMonth)) {
                            age = 13;
                            String mConfirmMessage = confirmationStatement();
                            intentShowAgeCategory.putExtra("Confirmation", mConfirmMessage);
                        } else {
                            age = 12;
                            String mConfirmMessage = confirmationStatement();
                            intentShowAgeCategory.putExtra("Confirmation", mConfirmMessage);
                        }
                        break;
                case "2010":
                    if (jan_july.contains(BirthMonth)) {
                        age = 12;
                        String mConfirmMessage = confirmationStatement();
                        intentShowAgeCategory.putExtra("Confirmation", mConfirmMessage);
                    } else {
                        age = 11;
                        String mConfirmMessage = confirmationStatement();
                        intentShowAgeCategory.putExtra("Confirmation", mConfirmMessage);
                    }
                    break;
                case "2011":
                    if (jan_july.contains(BirthMonth)) {
                        age = 11;
                        String mConfirmMessage = confirmationStatement();
                        intentShowAgeCategory.putExtra("Confirmation", mConfirmMessage);
                    } else {
                        age = 10;
                        String mConfirmMessage = confirmationStatement();
                        intentShowAgeCategory.putExtra("Confirmation", mConfirmMessage);
                    }
                    break;
                case "2012":
                    if (jan_july.contains(BirthMonth)) {
                        age = 10;
                        String mConfirmMessage = confirmationStatement();
                        intentShowAgeCategory.putExtra("Confirmation", mConfirmMessage);
                    } else {
                        age = 9;
                        String mConfirmMessage = confirmationStatement();
                        intentShowAgeCategory.putExtra("Confirmation", mConfirmMessage);
                    }
                    break;
                case "2013":
                    if (jan_july.contains(BirthMonth)) {
                        age = 9;
                        String mConfirmMessage = confirmationStatement();
                        intentShowAgeCategory.putExtra("Confirmation", mConfirmMessage);
                    } else {
                        age = 8;
                        String mConfirmMessage = confirmationStatement();
                        intentShowAgeCategory.putExtra("Confirmation", mConfirmMessage);
                    }
                    break;
                case "2014":
                    if (jan_july.contains(BirthMonth)) {
                        age = 8;
                        String mConfirmMessage = confirmationStatement();
                        intentShowAgeCategory.putExtra("Confirmation", mConfirmMessage);
                    } else {
                        age = 7;
                        String mConfirmMessage = confirmationStatement();
                        intentShowAgeCategory.putExtra("Confirmation", mConfirmMessage);
                    }
                    break;
                case "2015":
                    if (jan_july.contains(BirthMonth)) {
                        age = 7;
                        String mConfirmMessage = confirmationStatement();
                        intentShowAgeCategory.putExtra("Confirmation", mConfirmMessage);
                    } else {
                        age = 6;
                        String mConfirmMessage = confirmationStatement();
                        intentShowAgeCategory.putExtra("Confirmation", mConfirmMessage);
                    }
                    break;
                case "2016":
                    if (jan_july.contains(BirthMonth)) {
                        age = 6;
                        String mConfirmMessage = confirmationStatement();
                        intentShowAgeCategory.putExtra("Confirmation", mConfirmMessage);
                    } else {
                        age = 5;
                        String mConfirmMessage = confirmationStatement();
                        intentShowAgeCategory.putExtra("Confirmation", mConfirmMessage);
                    }
                    break;
                case "2017":
                    if (jan_july.contains(BirthMonth)) {
                        age = 5;
                        String mConfirmMessage = confirmationStatement();
                        intentShowAgeCategory.putExtra("Confirmation", mConfirmMessage);
                    } else {
                        age = 4;
                        String mConfirmMessage = confirmationStatement();
                        intentShowAgeCategory.putExtra("Confirmation", mConfirmMessage);
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    Log.i(TAG, "showAgeCategory: ");
    
    
            }
    
            //startActivity(intentShowAgeCategory);
            //method to access db and generate a list of events
            addEvents(age);
        }
    
        public void addEvents(int age) {
            //create instance of db access class and open db connection
            DatabaseAccess databaseAccess = DatabaseAccess.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
            databaseAccess.open();
    
            //Get age from showAgeCategory() and pass the value to the DatabaseAccess class
            String communityGamesAge = String.valueOf(age);
            String events = databaseAccess.getEvents(communityGamesAge);
    
            String mConfirmMessage = confirmationStatement();
    
            //Add output from query to show eventsList in the ConfirmationAndEvents Activity
            Intent intentShowAgeCategory = new Intent(this, ConfirmationAndEvents.class);
            intentShowAgeCategory.putExtra("Results",events);
            intentShowAgeCategory.putExtra("Confirmation",mConfirmMessage);
    
            databaseAccess.close();
    
            startActivity(intentShowAgeCategory);
        }
    
    
        //confirmation statement
        //private void confirmationStatement(String mBirthYear, int age){
        //private String confirmationStatement(String mBirthYear, String age){
        private String confirmationStatement(){
            String confirmAge  = "";
    
            if(age >= 16 || age == 4){
                confirmAge += "Your Community Games is " +age+ " as you will be" +age+ "on/before the 31st of July 2022"  + "\n";
                confirmAge += "Unfortunately, there are no events for your age group.";
            }else {
                confirmAge += "Your Community Games is " + age +  " as you will be"+ age + "on/before the 31st of July 2022" + "\n";
                confirmAge += "This means you can enter any event for " + "'Over " +age+"'" +" (or lower) and are 'Under"+(age+1)+"' "
                        +"or higher ";
            }
            return confirmAge;
        }
    
    
        private void showNearestClub() {
            Log.i(TAG, "showNearestClub: ");
    
            Intent intentShowNearestClub = new Intent(this , InteractiveMap.class);
            startActivity(intentShowNearestClub);
        }
    }
```

**Research already done to resolve the issue:**
I have already looked at the similar cases presented above here but none of them have helped.

Any advice would be much appreciated as I have an imminent deadline on 30.03.2022 to try to get it fixed.

**R.layout.dropdown_list_month**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:hint="@string/select_a_month">
</TextView>
```

**R.layout.dropdown_list_year**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:hint="@string/select_a_year">
</TextView>
```

**interactive_map.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewLogo"
        android:layout_width="114dp"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_cg_logo"
        android:contentDescription="@string/club_logo"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextEircode"
        android:layout_width="122dp"
        android:layout_height="43dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="144dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:hint="@string/eircode"
        android:text="@string/eircode"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:importantForAutofill="no" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="269dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="1dp"
        android:layout_width="379dp"
        android:layout_height="298dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.6"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spinnerAreas"
        android:contentDescription="@string/map_of_wicklow_community_games_catchment_areas"
        />
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerAreas"
        android:layout_width="378dp"
        android:layout_height="51dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:entries="@array/list_of_areas"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.52"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextEircode" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonContactUs"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/contact_us"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewAreaConfirmation" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewAreaConfirmation"
        android:layout_width="367dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:paddingStart="8dp"
        android:paddingEnd="8dp"
        android:text="@string/area_confirmation"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/webView" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: what is the code for the `R.layout.dropdown_list_month` and year?

Comment: `Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{...InteractiveMap}` – The problem is in `InteractiveMap`'s layout, not `MainActivity`'s. Looks like a problem with a color resource used on a `<Spinner>` there, possibly not available on the version that's crashing.

Comment: R.layout.dropdown_list_month and year added and code for 'interactive_map'.

Comment: That stack trace is (was) saying that the `spinnerAreas` `<Spinner>` has an invalid color for its `android:backgroundTint` attribute. That attribute is obviously not explicitly set on the `<Spinner>` in the given layout, so just to make sure, are you certain that is the layout that you're passing to `setContentView()` in `InteractiveMap`'s `onCreate()`? If so, do you possibly have more than one of the `interactive_map` layout; e.g, one each for portrait and layout, or for different Android versions, or screen sizes, etc.? Have you possibly set a value for `android:backgroundTint` in the theme?

Comment: Thanks Mike I'll try your suggestions.

Comment: I had to cut some of the log file output so that I could include more code. Yes, setContentView() in InteractiveMap's is set in onCreate. Only one interactive_map layout exists. I have not made any prevision for Android versions, or screen sizes. I removed android:backgroundTint based on your first post. I have also tried adding 'configurations {
    all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force 'androidx.databinding:databinding-common:7.1.2'
            force 'androidx.databinding:baseLibrary:3.2.0-alpha11'
        }
    }
}' to build.gradle

Comment: "I had to cut some of the log file output so that I could include more code." – Yeah, I know; that was just for other users who might wonder where I got the specifics from. "I removed android:backgroundTint based on your first post." – Where did you remove it from? I don't think I saw it here anywhere. Beyond that, I'm not sure what the gradle stuff is for, 'cause this doesn't seem to be a dependency issue, just something with your particular setup. It's starting to sound like a theme issue, actually, if you mean that it's still giving the exact same error and stack trace.